# Comparar hora actual con hora de entrada y hora de salida

Tags: c#

Hola estoy programando con c#; bien tengo una variable que muestra la hora inicial y tengo otras dos variables que muestran la hora de entrada y la otra muestra hora de salida, lo que quiero hacer es que si la hora actual es superior o igual a la hora de entrada e inferior igual a la hora de salida que el texto Grupo A sea visible; de la manera que lo he echo me marca error. El error es que me dicen que no se pueden hacer ese tipo de comparaciones a variables de tipo string.

```
  public bool groupeA(string timeGA)
    {
        bool ga = false;
        var timeEntree = DateTime.Now.ToString("08:00:00");
        var timeSortie = DateTime.Now.ToString("13:30:00");

        if (timeGA >= timeEntree && timeGA <= timeSortie)
        {
            ga = true;
            bunifuLabel_GroupeActive.Visible = true;
            bunifuLabel_GroupeActive.Text = "GROUPE A";
        }
        else
        {
            bunifuLabel_GroupeActive.Visible = true;
            bunifuLabel_GroupeActive.Text = "GROUPE B";
        }


        return ga;

    }
```

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Estas comparando un `DateTime` con un `string` (`string timeGA`). Empieza por solucionar eso.

Comment: Roger tome gracias he resuelto lo que me ha dicho, he avanzado un poco pero ahora el problema esta en como establezco una hora fija a una variable de  datetime . osea en vez de poner HH:mm:ss pongo 08:00:00;

Comment: @RogerTorné en realidad esta comparando entre strings... pero no hay mayor y menor entre strings...

Comment: deberias comparar todo como datetime.. que para eso tiene funciones de comparacion!

Comment: Cómo sabes que un string es mayor que otro? Te has preguntado eso? No tiene más sentido comparar dos instancia de alguna clase que esté hecha para manejar datos de fechas y/u horas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen dia, te estas confundiendo como dicen los comentarios estas comparando cadenas de texto cuando pones ToString estas pasando el tiempo actual a cadena de texo
lo mejor es crear una funcion que compare los tres valores, hora actual, hora inicio y hora final aqui te dejo una funcion, pero hay varias maneras de resolver esto,
la llame IsWithinTime solo te dice que si tu hora inicial se encuentra dentro de un rango.

Salutes.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        //prueba 
        string stringNowTime = "6:00 AM";
        string stringStartTime = "7:00 AM";
        string stringEndTime = "1:30 PM";
        
        if( IsWithinTime(stringNowTime, stringStartTime, stringEndTime) )
           {
           Console.WriteLine("Dentro de horario");
           }
           
           else
           {
           Console.WriteLine("Fuera de horario");
           }
        
    }
    
    public static bool IsWithinTime(string stringNowTime,string stringStartTime , string stringEndTime) 
    {

        var nowTime = DateTime.Parse(stringNowTime);
        var startTime = DateTime.Parse(stringStartTime);
        var endTime = DateTime.Parse(stringEndTime);            

        if ((nowTime <= endTime) && (nowTime>=  startTime) )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias hermanos he resuelto el problema DIOS os bendiga a todos

Comment: @NguemaAutomobile si esta respuesta te ha ayudado, considera marcarla como aceptada. De esa manera, agradeces al autor e indicas a futuros usuarios con el mismo problema que esta respuesta es la que te ayudó. Un saludo